# How to position image above other image on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation, mouseover

I tried to find any solution but I coudn't find.
I have some images that each one is on the other.I want that when I mouseover the first image the images that behnd will be above the first image.
For example:

Normal: [image]
Mouseover: [image]

In the basic the second and the third image is behind the first image.
Sorry for my english and thanks in advance!

Comment: for required effects only two image is enough

Comment: post what have you tried so far !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution requires the boxes to be absolutely positioned and in a container.

```js
var prop = "bottom",
  moveAmount = 50;

$('.container').hover(
  function() {
    var moved = $(this).find(".box");

    for (var i = (moved.length - 1), pad = 0; i >= 0; i--) {
      $(moved[i]).css(prop, (pad++ * moveAmount) + "px");
    }
  },
  function() {
    var moved = $(this).find(".box");
 
    for (var i = 0; i < moved.length; i++) {
      $(moved[i]).css(prop, "0px");
    }
  }
);
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  position: relative;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}

.box {
  background: red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;

  transition: bottom 0.3s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's `hover` event function with the `over` and `out` handlers..

1. Begin with the boxes that are "behind" the first box -  hide them.
2. Next define an `onhover` event to display them when mouse is hovering, and to hide them again when mouse is out of hover.

```js
$('#1').hover(
  function(){
    $('.hidden').removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
  },
  function(){
    $('.visible').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
  }
)
```

```css
.box {
  border: solid 2px black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.visible {
  visibility: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="3" class="box hidden">3</div>
<div id="2" class="box hidden">2</div>
<div id="1" class="box">1</div>
```

Comment: I think he needs the images to be behind `1`, meaning `1` is on top of them. In your example, they are just stacked, but hidden.